# Get HTTPS protocol in server side

Tags: java, https, server

We are trying to get the HTTPS protocol used (SSLv3, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2) in the client request to our service, we need to keep track of it.

We know how to get it from a Java client (later the example) but we want to recover from the server side, is there anyway to do it?

```
public String getProtocol(){
   String protocol = "";

   if(s != null){
       try{
           SSLSession session = ((SSLSocket) s).getSession();
           protocol = session.getProtocol();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           log.error("Error: ",e);
       }
   }

   return protocol 
}
```

Comment: you can do it using HttpServletRequest http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure%28%29

Comment: What is the object `s`

Comment: Why precisely do you "need to keep track of it" ?  Your code (preumably java EE Servlet code) belongs to the application layer, whereas all the encryption stuff belongs to another, lower, layer, from which the application layer *should* be shielded.  So in principle not having that info available in the application layer is not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: i know that it is a feature, but in here in venezuela we are in process called "Reconversion Monetaria" (Monetary Reconvertion), where the state determited that all operation, money and any finatial instrument must be divede by 1000, to add more salt in the injure, they want to implement TLS1.2 comunications in all finatial channels, so we need to know how are still using SSLv3, TLSv1.0 and TLS1.1 to call them and inform that they need to change their platform, and to keep track of the porcentange of the change process, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Erwin Smout, is any way i can access that lower layer, in handler, or filter ?

Comment: If i get this right, you are running an HTTPS service and you want to figure out if any client is attempting to connect using any TLS version other than TLSv1.2...Is that correct? Which HTTPS server you are using - is it your code or third party? If its your code, it should be easy to get from TLS session. If it is third party, which one you are using...Another way is to just do a packet capture, if that is possible, and look in to the hand shake message.

Comment: Rajesh, i want to know what is using the client, so we can contact them and inform that they need to change,, the server i am using is Resin 4.0.55.